# Select the first 10 rows - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

So far I have the following model:

```
class Listing extends Eloquent {
     //Class Logic HERE
}
```

I want a basic function that retrieves the first 10 rows of my table "listings" and passes them on to the view (via a controller?).

I know this a very basic task but I can't find a simple guide that actually explains step-by-step how to display a basic set of results, whilst detailing what is required in the model, controller and view files.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

First you can use a Paginator. This is as simple as:

```
$allUsers = User::paginate(15);

$someUsers = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(15);
```

The variables will contain an instance of Paginator class. all of your data will be stored under `data` key.

Or you can do something like:

Old versions Laravel.

```
Model::all()->take(10)->get();
```

Newer version Laravel.

```
Model::all()->take(10);
```

For more reading consider these links:

- [pagination docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage)
- [passing data to views](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)
- [Eloquent basic usage](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)
- [A cheat sheet](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/)

Comment: Thank you Vit, I was unaware Laravel had this feature and it's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I think you'll find its:  ->take(10)->get();

Comment: @Joeri  sure that is, updated the answer to be precise, thank you.

Comment: I think the `get();` argument has now gone on the newer versions laravel

Comment: I used `Model::take(10)->get()` without problems on 5.2

Comment: `Model::take(10)->get();` is not working in laravel 5.4

Comment: Well, @AdarshSojitra, the documentation says it is still possible, checkout the Eloquent section of the docs http://joxi.ru/nAyoDzhYNM99mZ

Comment: Another option is to get the underlying QB object and apply to it directly ,

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\Users\saber\Documents\saberprojects\behplus\survey-service\database\factories\TaggableFactory.php on line 28 and at l
east 1 expected

Comment: Using all() is a wast of time and resources cause before load all the table and then get only the first 10 `Modell::take(10)->get()` is much faster

Comment: ```fetching ::all() ``` already fetch and stored everything in collection then chunk it by  take(10) which is  inefficient

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way in laravel 5 is:

```
$listings=Listing::take(10)->get();

return view('view.name',compact('listings'));
```

Comment: I will say, perfect answer.

Answer (score 26):

Another way to do it is using a `limit` method:

```
Listing::limit(10)->get();
```

This can be useful if you're not trying to implement pagination, but for example, return 10 random rows from a table:

```
Listing::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 7):

this worked as well IN **LARAVEL 8** and 9 and 10 and above

```
Model::query()->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked in Laravel 9

```
Model::query()->take(10)->get();
```