# how to get the first item in the collection when using one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a little problem but it's frustrating me a lot.

I have two tables
1. users
2. posts

The **user** can have many posts and the post belongs to one user

**My question : how to get the first post when typing the relation?**

```
public function index() {
 $user = User::find(1); 

// here it will return all posts

$user->with('posts');

    return view('home.index',compact('user'));
}
```

**By the way : i used closure but it didn't work ... it return all users with posts**

```
public function index()
    {

        $user = User::find(1);


        $user = $user->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->first();
        }])->get();

        return $user ;
        return view('home.index',compact('user'));
    }
```

**and the result is like that :**

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Barney Walter",
"email": "wuckert.murphy@example.org",
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"posts": []
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Dr. Makenzie Rutherford",
"email": "estroman@example.com",
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"posts": []
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Ernesto Shanahan",
"email": "pwill@example.com",
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"posts": []
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Rosalinda Cartwright",
"email": "josefa.murazik@example.com",
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"posts": []
},
{
"id": 5,
"name": "Kyleigh Willms",
"email": "ddach@example.net",
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:48:45",
"posts": [
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": 5,
"name": "Malcolm Simonis",
"title": "Autem quidem quia earum ipsam. A a commodi id adipisci quia minima iste numquam. Eum eius odit porro veniam. Et iure occaecati sapiente minima et beatae. Labore eius labore accusamus sapiente sed eveniet accusamus.",
"is_published": 1,
"created_at": "2016-12-22 10:54:14",
"updated_at": "2016-12-22 10:54:14"
}
]
}
]
```

**any help about that ... please !!**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what answer to give because your question is unclear. What should the intended result be? Do you want to filter the users based on having one or more posts or do you want to show all users and only their first post?

Comment: Not know Laravel as Much, But based on Logic, i can say that you can try Pagination or Paged Query for your Posts result. and than you can get how many Posts you need.
Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255508/select-the-first-10-rows-laravel-eloquent?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: yes ... I want to show  specific user and only his  first post ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `take()`:

```
$user = User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->take(1);
        }])->first();
```

And `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')` will sort result, so you'll take the very first post.

Comment: This is almost right. You just have to replace the `first()` method with the `find($id)` method for the User model. The `with()` closure looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get just 1 post.

```
$user = User::with('posts')->first();
$user->setRelation('posts', $business->posts->take(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a model `object` of `post` instead of `collection` then you can define a new `hasOne` relation in `User` model as:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

And then you can query it as:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->with('post')->first();
```