# Fetch only few data from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to fetch only 4 rows from my database's table.

`$data=table::all();`

Returns all data/rows from my table. How can I get only 4 rows instead of all?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try searching before posting a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the first 10 rows - Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255508/select-the-first-10-rows-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$data=table::take(4);` that will only retrieve the 4 first records.

You also have the `limit()` method. See details in the [Laravel Limit & Offset docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset).

Comment: My pleasure, please consider accepting my post as the answer if it suits you. Still, for a simple query like yours, a quick google search about "Laravel limit query" would have been enough :)